# Update/redraw canvas on clicking a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

I'm using cirque.js plugin to show circle percentage values drawn with a canvas.

Here's a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/8d9sw1yg/1/) I made that should contain all the info with plugin code.

Initially, the circle gets drawn correctly, with the correct value.

**Issue**: When I try to update the value via a function on clicking a button, nothing happens, not working, I think the canvas needs to be drawn again with the new value?

**Q**: How can I update the circle percentage value asynchronously?

```
$('.cirque').cirque ({ //this works
    radius: 40,
    value: 65,
    total: 100,
    trackColor: '#ccc',
    arcColor: '#5cb85c',
    label: 'percent',
    lineWidth: 12
});

$('#update').click(function (e) { 
    updateCircle(50); //this does not work
});

function updateCircle(val){ 
    $('.cirque').cirque ({
        radius: 40,
        value: val,
        total: 100,
        trackColor: '#ccc',
        arcColor: '#5cb85c',
        label: 'percent',
        lineWidth: 12
    });
}
```

Comment: Your fiddle does not seem to include JQuery

Comment: I've included jquery

Comment: We don't yet have cross-browser async operations in javascript. We have edge capabilities like webworkers & promises. While we're waiting, instead of toggling a timeout or an interval  (set|clear), use a `requestAnimationFrame` loop. It is non-blocking during its wait-state, it coordinates with the display refresh cycle and it automatically sends in a timestamp argument that can be used to throttle operations more efficiently than toggling timeouts|intervals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've not find any function to update value in this plugin. But you can update value with a trick. Replace the `div` having class `cirque` with a same `div` and initialize it with new value like following. Hope this will help you.

```
function updateCircle(val){
    var cirque=$('<div class="cirque"></div>');
    $('.cirque').replaceWith(cirque);

    cirque.cirque ({
         radius: 40,
         value: val,
         total: 100,
         trackColor: '#ccc',
         arcColor: '#5cb85c',
         label: 'percent',
         lineWidth: 12
    }); 
}
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/8d9sw1yg/2/